# PHP 5.2 to 5.3 Upgrade Change for Call By Reference

Tags: php-5.3, php-5.2

I am involved in upgrading a php application from PHP 5.2 to PHP 5.3. In the PHP migration docs it says that "The behaviour of functions with by-reference parameters called by value has changed...". I have been trying to understand what this is referring to, and in all cases I have tested the behavior is identical in 5.2 and 5.3.

Can anyone provide an example where the behavior of 5.2 is different than 5.3 with respect to call by reference?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    function foo(&$var)
    {
        $var++;
    }

    //foo(5);
    //PHP Fatal error:  Only variables can be passed by reference

    $a = 5;
    foo($a);
    // $a is 6 here

    echo $a;
?>
```